# Use AWS JS SDK in node to describe all ec2 instances

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I've been using `AWS JS SDK` in `node` and I wanted to describe my existing `ec2` istances in all the regions, but I get an empty `reservation[]`. I tried to specify a region using
`AWS.config.update{}` and it worked as expected and it returned the instances, but this is what I want. I want to query AWS for all my instances, without specifying a region. Is there a simple way!? 
( I'm using my smartphone to ask this question, I can't access my computer right now).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Amazon Web Services docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html),

> For example, if you need to access Amazon EC2 objects in multiple
>   regions, create an EC2 service object for each region and then set the
>   region configuration of each service object accordingly.

```
var ec2_regionA = new AWS.EC2({region: 'ap-southeast-2', maxRetries: 15, apiVersion: '2014-10-01'});
var ec2_regionB = new AWS.EC2({region: 'us-east-1', maxRetries: 15, apiVersion: '2014-10-01'});
```

My implementation,

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var EC2Objects = [
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'us-east-1'}),      //N. Virginia
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'us-east-2'}),      //Ohio
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'us-west-1'}),      //N. California
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'us-west-2'}),      //Oregon
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'ca-central-1'}),   //Canada (Central)
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'eu-west-1'}),      //Ireland
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'eu-central-1'}),   //Frankfurt
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'eu-west-2'}),      //London
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'ap-northeast-1'}), //Tokyo
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'ap-northeast-2'}), //Seoul
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'ap-southeast-1'}), //Singapore
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'ap-southeast-2'}), //Syndney
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'ap-south-1'}),     //Mumbai
    new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15',region: 'sa-east-1'})       //Sao Paulo
];

var instances = [];
listEc2();

function listEc2(){
    var params = {};
    for(var i=0; i<EC2Objects.length; i++){
        EC2Objects[i].describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     ec2ListBuilderCallback(data);           // successful response
        });
    }
}

function ec2ListBuilderCallback(data){
    instances.push(data); 
    if(instances.length == EC2Objects.length){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(instances));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[{"ReservationId":"r-0e7c0a2e3cf30944c","Groups":[],"Instances":[{"InstanceId":"i-0391f0e44b04675ad","ImageId":"ami-0b33d91d","State":{"Code":16,"Name":"running"}],{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]},{"Reservations":[]}]
```

I cut off the output for the region I am using because it was really long.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through each region, and make the call once for each region. The API is region specific, you can't get the list of all EC2 instances in all regions in a single API call.